# Set python turtle's heading in the direction of the line

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I have made a line using the python turtle module. Here's the code:

```
import turtle

t = turtle.Turtle()
def line(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    t.penup()
    t.setpos(x1, y1)
    t.pendown()
    t.setpos(x2, y2)
```

Here's how the output looks like: (with `line(0, 0, 100, 100)`)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzv9P.png)

The turtle's heading is 0.0. I need to set it in the direction of the line drawn so that if I do `t.fd(50)` it continues drawing the line.

I get the coordinates of the line from the user so how do I align the turtle's heading to the line?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Learn to Read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.left). just use `t.left(45)`

Comment: Hi, I know that. Actually I am getting the input from the user for the coordinates of the line and then the turtle is drawing it. So I don't know what the user enters and I want to align the turtle to the line.

Comment: Write your complete code and ask your question [right](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so the users can help you

Comment: Ok, thanks! Changed!

Comment: This is a math problem, not a programming problem. How would you find the [angle that the line makes with the horizontal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slope) given the coordinates of two points on the line? Once you have this angle, simply do [`setheading()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.setheading)

Comment: Ok, will try and revert!

Comment: Thank you! Did it using trigonometry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than trigonometry, you can simply use turtle's `towards()` method in conjunction with `setheading()` to point to the target before moving to it:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def line(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.setpos(x1, y1)
    turtle.pendown()

    turtle.setheading(turtle.towards(x2, y2))
    turtle.setpos(x2, y2)

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()

line(0, 0, 100, 100)

screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]